# Keep excel cell format as text with "date like" data

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, closedxml

This seems silly, but I haven't been able to get my values in the format of `#/####` to write as the literal string rather than becoming formatted as a date within excel.

I'm using ClosedXML to write to excel, and using the following:

```
// snip
IXLRangeRow tableRow = tableRowRange.Row(1);
tableRow.Cell(1).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
tableRow.Cell(1).Value = "2/1997";
// snip
```

Looking at the output excel sheet I get in the cell `2/1/1997` - even though I'm setting the format as text in code, I'm getting it as a "Date" in the excel sheet - I checked this by right clicking the cell, format cell, seeing "date" as the format.

If I change things up to:

```
// snip
IXLRangeRow tableRow = tableRowRange.Row(1);
tableRow.Cell(1).Value = "2/1997";
tableRow.Cell(1).DataType = XLCellValues.Text;
// snip
```

I instead get `35462` as my output.

I just want my literal value of `2/1997` to be displayed on the worksheet.  Please advise on how to correct.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try this

```
ws.Cell(rowCounter, colCounter).SetValue<string>(Convert.ToString(fieldValue));
```

Comment: This worked for me but can anyone comment on why this works??

Comment: I was also able to trim down the code above to this knowing that my `fieldValue` was already a string: 
`ws.Cell(rowCounter, colCounter).SetValue(fieldValue);`

Comment: @jaredbaszler this is a documented in the Wiki for ClosedXML. If you set a value using cell.Value = blah it always does automatic conversion of the values for you so it automatically recognizes the string as a date and converts it (much like Excel annoyingly does with CSV files by default). However the cell.SetValue() specifically avoids this and if the value is a string, it remains a string in the Excel file.

Comment: wiki mentioned by @KendallBennett https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Text-with-numbers-are-getting-converted-to-numbers

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about from ClosedXML, but maybe try Range.NumberFormat ([MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196401.aspx))

For example...

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Or

```
Selection.NumberFormat = "#/####"
```

Comment: This indeed works:

worksheet.Range(firstCell, lastCell).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
tableRow.Cell(1).Value = "'2/1997";
```

Note the single quote.

Comment: that's pretty close - my only issue with it is if i hit F2 or enter the formula bar on the cell, the format then gets updated to date in the format of "mmm/yyyy".  Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

```
ws.Cell(rowCounter, colCounter).Value="'"+Convert.ToString(fieldValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

Formatting has to be done before you write values to the cells.

I had following mechanism, run after I make worksheet, right before I save it:

```
    private void SetColumnFormatToText(IXLWorksheet worksheet)
    {
        var wholeSheet = worksheet.Range(FirstDataRowIndexInExcel, StartCellIndex, RowCount, HeaderCount);
        wholeSheet.Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
    }
```

which didn't do squat.
[image]

Doing it before I write values to the cells in  a row did it.

```
worksheet.Range(RowIndex, StartCellIndex, RowIndex, EndCellIndex).Style.NumberFormat.Format = "@";
```

with cell value assignments following immediately after.
[image]